# Creating a Pivot table macro - Need to remove the marked rows through code

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I want the marked rows (subtotals) gone, here is the code for my Pivot table (I am coding a macro) any suggestions?
[See picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYGo8.jpg)

```
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=ActiveSheet.UsedRange).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddFields RowFields:="Kostenstellen-Nr"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddFields RowFields:="Konto-Nr"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddFields RowFields:="Betrag Brutto"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Kostenstellen-Nr").Orientation = xlRowField
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Konto-Nr").Orientation = xlRowField
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Betrag Brutto"), "Sum of Betrag Brutto", xlSum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about subtotals, you record a macro and change it via the top ribbon (PivotTable Tools/Design).

Add this line to your code :

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Kostenstellen-Nr").Subtotals = Array( _
    False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
```

Comment: @L.J.G : Glad I could help, but plz take a minute to take the tour : http://stackoverflow.com/tour and discover how to accept answers! ;)